# Am I a bad programmer?

Tags: interface-design

I've started to ask myself for the past months if I am a good programmer, I graduated Computer science 3 months ago but I've been working as a programmer since first year in University. Since 1 year I am working on a very big company. The problem that bothers me it's that I need to handle my design on my apps alone. It's not bothering me doing design on my own apps, I would enjoy this very much if I wouldn't get frustrated because I don't know how to combine 2 or more colours or to design a window.
What should I do to improve myself on designing skills ? I am doing excellent on coding part.

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to ask this on [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)? Also you do not specify whet part of design your doing. Obviously you need to design the interaction somehow if you do any public facing things. But this is not automatically a graphics design issue per see. But the question: Should you be doing graphic design unless its actually part of your job description is murky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely no your not a bad programmer, it is probably that you are just suffering from the [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome). As for doing the graphical design for your applications as opposed seems to be rather common in projects that do not have a separate budget for it.

Does it make you a bad programmer? Only in the sense that a bricklayer makes for a bad plumber. You can not achieve everything. On the other hand you are the authority on what the software does in these small projects.

This is one of the partial message of the UX crowd in that the person best suited for the job should do the job. The interaction is strongly influences with all design decisions even ones that have nothing to do with graphic design. You'd database design affects how your GUI reflection will look like to some extent. better database design thus leads to better end results in teh user interaction layer.